# Solr suggester in SolrCloud mode

Tags: solr, lucene, solr4j

I am running the solr in CloudSolr mode with three shards. The data is already indexed into solr. Now I have configured the solr suggester in solrconfig.xml. This is the configuration from solrconfig file. I am using solr 4.10 version.

```
<searchComponent name="suggest" class="solr.SuggestComponent">
    <lst name="suggester">
        <str name="name">mysuggest</str>
        <str name="lookupImpl">FuzzyLookupFactory</str>
        <str name="storeDir">suggester_fuzzy_dir</str>
        <str name="dictionaryImpl">DocumentDictionaryFactory</str>
        <str name="field">businessName</str>
        <str name="payloadField">profileId</str>
        <str name="weightField">businessName</str>
        <str name="suggestAnalyzerFieldType">text_general</str>
        <str name="buildOnStartup">false</str>
    </lst>
</searchComponent>

<requestHandler name="/suggest" class="solr.SearchHandler" startup="lazy">
    <lst name="defaults">
        <str name="suggest">true</str>
        <str name="suggest.count">10</str>
    </lst>
    <arr name="components">
        <str>suggest</str>
    </arr>
</requestHandler>
```

Here is the command I am using to fetch the result:

```
http://shard1:8900/solr/core/suggest?suggest=true&suggest.build=true&suggest.reload&suggest.dictionary=mysuggest&wt=json&indent=true&suggest.q=sale
```

This is the output of the command:

```
{
"responseHeader":{
"status":0,
"QTime":1490},
"command":"build",
"suggest":{}
}
```

Nothing is coming into suggest result. I have 10K records indexed into solr.

I am seeing the following into log file:

```
org.apache.solr.handler.component.SuggestComponent; http://shard1:8983/solr/core/ : null
org.apache.solr.handler.component.SuggestComponent; http://shard2:8900/solr/core/ : null
org.apache.solr.handler.component.SuggestComponent; http://shard3:7574/solr/core/ : null
```

I am not able understand what is missing here. Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It was not working because solr was running in SolrCloud mode. There is two ways to perform suggestion in solrCloud mode:

- Use the **distrib=false** parameter. This will fetch the data from only one shard which you are accessing in the command. You can add the following into Component definition itself.

  ```
    <bool name="distrib">false</bool>
  ```
- Use the **shards** and **shards.qt** parameter for searching all the shards. The shards parameter will contain comma separated list of all the shards which you want to include in the query. The shards.qt parameter will define the reat API you want to access.

> **shards.qt:**  Signals Solr that requests to shards should be sent to a request handler given by this parameter. Use shards.qt=/spell when making the request if your request handler is "/spell".
>
> **shards:** shards=solr-shard1:8983/solr,solr-shard2:8983/solr [Distributed Search](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/DistributedSearch)

Please check [Here](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/SpellCheckComponent#Distributed_Search_Support) for more details.

Comment: Thanks, was able to solve adding shards.qt to the default query parameters.