# Spellcheck Solr: solr.DirectSolrSpellChecker config

Tags: solr, lucene, spell-checking

I am trying to test the spellchecking functionality with Solr 4.7.2 using solr.DirectSolrSpellChecker (where you don't need to build a dedicated index).

I have a field named "title" in my index; I used a copy field definition to create a field named "title_spell" to be queried for the spellcheck (title_spell is correctly filled). However, in the admin solr admin console, I always get empty suggesions.

For example: I have a solr document with the title "A B automobile"; I enter in the admin console (spellcheck crossed and under the input field spellcheck.q) "atuomobile". I expect to get at least something like "A B automobile" or "automobile" but the spellcheck suggestion remains empty...

My configuration:

schema.xml (only relevant part copied):

```
    <fieldType name="textSpell" class="solr.TextField" positionIncrementGap="100" omitNorms="true">
        <analyzer type="index">
            <tokenizer class="solr.StandardTokenizerFactory"/>
            <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
            <filter class="solr.StandardFilterFactory"/>
        </analyzer>
        <analyzer type="query">
            <tokenizer class="solr.StandardTokenizerFactory"/>
            <filter class="solr.SynonymFilterFactory" synonyms="de_DE/synonyms.txt" ignoreCase="true"
                    expand="true"/>
            <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
            <filter class="solr.StandardFilterFactory"/>
        </analyzer>
    </fieldType>
    ...
    <field name="title_spell" type="textSpell" indexed="true" stored="true" multiValued="false"/>
```

solr.xml (only relevant part copied):

```
<searchComponent name="spellcheck" class="solr.SpellCheckComponent">
    <str name="queryAnalyzerFieldType">textSpell</str>
    <lst name="spellchecker">
        <str name="name">default</str>
        <str name="field">title_spell</str>
        <str name="classname">solr.DirectSolrSpellChecker</str>
        <str name="distanceMeasure">internal</str>
        <float name="accuracy">0.5</float>
        <int name="maxEdits">2</int>
        <int name="minPrefix">1</int>
        <int name="maxInspections">5</int>
        <int name="minQueryLength">4</int>
        <float name="maxQueryFrequency">0.01</float>
        <float name="thresholdTokenFrequency">.01</float>
    </lst>
</searchComponent>
...
<requestHandler name="standard" class="solr.SearchHandler" default="true">
    <lst name="defaults">
        <str name="defType">edismax</str>
        <str name="echoParams">explicit</str>
    </lst>
    <!--Versuch, das online datum mit in die Gewichtung zu nehmen...-->
    <lst name="appends">
        <str name="bf">recip(ms(NOW/MONTH,sort_date___d_i_s),3.16e-11,50,1)</str>
        <!--<str name="qf">title___td_i_s_gcopy^1e-11</str>-->
        <str name="qf">title___td_i_s_gcopy^21</str>
        <str name="q.op">AND</str>
    </lst>


    <arr name="last-components">
        <str>spellcheck</str>
    </arr>
</requestHandler>
```

What did I miss? Thanks for your answers!

Comment: can you provide your query url which you are using?

Comment: The url looks like this:

Comment: localhost:8080/solr/service/select?q=*%3A*&wt=json&indent=true&spellcheck=true&spellcheck.q=atuomobile

Comment: Did you find the solution?

Answer (score 2):

How large is your index? For a small index (think less than a few million docs), you're going to have to tune `accuracy`, `maxQueryFrequency`, and `thresholdTokenFrequency`. (Actually, it would probably be worth doing this on larger indices as well.)

For example, my 1.5 million doc index uses the following for these settings:

```
      <float name="maxQueryFrequency">0.01</float>
      <float name="thresholdTokenFrequency">.00001</float>
      <float name="accuracy">0.5</float>
```

`accuracy` tells Solr how accurate a result needs to be before it's considered worth returning as a suggestion.

`maxQueryFrequency` tells Solr how frequently the term needs to occur in the index before it's can be considered worth returning as a suggestion.

`thresholdTokenFrequency` tells Solr what percentage of documents the term must be included in before it's considered worth returning as a suggestion.

If you plan to use spellchecking on multiple phrases, you may need to add a `ShingleFilter` to your `title_spell` field.

Another thing you might try is setting your `queryAnalyzerFieldType` to `title_spell`.

Comment: The index is really small; 1500 at the moment, won't grow over 10000 in the next years. I ve tried to change queryAnalyzerFieldType but it didn't help, i will try to tune the other parameters

Comment: You definitely need to tune those parameters, then. Your threshold and query frequency are probably going to be really, really low.

Answer (score 0):

Can you please try editing your `requestHandler` declaration.

```
<requestHandler name="/standard" class="solr.SearchHandler" default="true">
```

and query url as:

`http://localhost:8080/solr/service/standard?q=<term>&qf=title_spell`

First experiment with small terms and learn how it is behaving. One problem here is it will only return all the terms starting with the same `query term`. You can use `FuzzyLookupFactory` which will match and return fuzzy result. For more information check [solr suggester wiki](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/Suggester).

Comment: I've tried to edit the requestHandler but it didn't help. I will look into the configuration for fuzzy search

Comment: @R.. which mode are you running solr? If you are using CloudSolr mode then query like [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32045700/solr-suggester-in-solrcloud-mode).